# Get child pages of current page as well as current page link

Tags: php, wordpress

I intend to create a sidebar to retrieve a list of the current page's children as well as the current page itself. Here is the code that I have been using which retrieves the current pages children even when on the child pages, however when I try to include the `$parent` as `$post->post_parent` it displays all pages

```
    <?php
   if ($post->post_parent)  {
        $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
        $root=count($ancestors)-1;
        $parent = $ancestors[$root];
    } else {
        $parent = $post->ID;
    }
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=". $parent ."&echo=0");
    $parent = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=". $post->post_parent ."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <?php echo  $parent ?>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please add the _actual_ result of your code and your expectations. People do not like to guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Return parent page ID or child as else. Add this to functions.php
---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function get_top_parent_page_id() { 
    global $post; 

    if ($post->ancestors) { 
        return end($post->ancestors); 
    } else { 
        return $post->ID; 
    } 
}
```

//Use this in the template

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

    //Add parent page slug into arguments
    $query = new WP_Query('pagename=page_slug');
    if ($query->have_posts() ){ while ($query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); } }

    //Get children by calling function in functions.php for the top parent id                  
    $current_page_id = get_top_parent_page_id();
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'safaris', 'post_parent' => $current_page_id, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
    $child_query = new WP_Query($args);

    $i = 0; 
    if ($child_query->have_posts() ){ while ($child_query->have_posts() ){ $child_query->the_post(); 
    $i++; if( 1 == $i ) { ?>

    <li role="presentation" class="active"><?php the_title(); ?></li>

    <?php } else { ?>

    <li role="presentation"><?php the_title(); ?></li>

    <?php } } } wp_reset_postdata();  endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I used this a while back. It can help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked.

```
<?php if ( !is_page()) { ?>
    <div class="card recentPosts">
        <h3>Recent posts</h3>
        <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 4, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
        $postslist = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'thumbnail', true);
        ?>
            <a class="recentposts" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>">
                <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                echo '<div class="aside image">';
                the_post_thumbnail( 'sidebarThumb' );
                echo '</div>';
                }
                ?>

            <div class="title">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <div class="meta">
                    <div class="metaItem postedon">
                        <?php echo get_the_date('F y'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="metaItem author">
                        <?php
                                global $post;
                            $fname = get_the_author_meta('first_name');
                            $lname = get_the_author_meta('last_name');
                            $full_name = '';

                            if( empty($fname)){
                                $full_name = $lname;
                            } elseif( empty( $lname )){
                                $full_name = $fname;
                            } else {
                                //both first name and last name are present
                                $full_name = "{$fname} {$lname}";
                            }

                            echo 'By '.$full_name;
                            ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="feature-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image_url[0];  ?> );"></div>
        </a>
        <hr />
        <?php endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```